# Mimikatz /rc4 argument for pass-the-ticket?

Tags: windows, kerberos, microsoft, mimikatz

I'm studying how pass-the-ticket works using Mimikatz, i.e., forged Silver and Golden Kerberos tickets.

The command usually takes the form (Golden tickets):

```
kerberos::golden /sid:SID /domain:DOMAIN /rc4:RC4 /user:USER /id:ID /ptt
```

The command for Silver tickets takes the `/rc4` parameter as well.

Can someone tell me what this parameter is for, and how to obtain the necessary information?

Comment: It's supposed to be the NTLM hash for the account. Acquiring this hash is the fundamental attack.

Comment: @Steve - Thank you for your comment. I have two questions: (1) What if you create a fake user (this is possible with Silver/Golden tickets)? (2) Why "NTLM" hash? The parameter says "RC4", which is a stream cipher (not an MD4 hash).

Answer (score 2):

the `/rc4` parameter tells mimikatz to **encrypt** the ticket using the **RC4** algorithm – and the KEY you specify with it. Mimikatz doesn't really care if that KEY is a valid password hash nor does it care if it is even a NTLM hash or just some garbage in the first place. However, it *has to be* the valid NTLM password hash of the targeted service in order to generate a valid ticket.